# google maps dynamically created marker click event uses same marker

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

SO i have a ajax post that gets a lot of destinations from my database. 
I iterate through them and adds a marker on my map for each one of them. 
I also add a click event for each one of them so i will be able to click on them but the click event gets the last marker created as input so it doesn't matter which one of them i press i will always get the same marker in my click event.
Here is my code:

```
    success: function (data) {
        for (destination in data) {
            var latlng = { lat: data[destination].Latitude, lng: data[destination].Longitude }
            console.log(data[destination].Id);
            console.log(data[destination]);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                postion: new google.maps.LatLng(latlng.lat, latlng.lng),

            });
            marker.set("id", data[destination].Id);

            marker.setIcon( /** {google.maps.Icon} */({
                url: '/Content/Markers/green_MarkerX.png',
                size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
                origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
                scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35)
            }));
            marker.setPosition(latlng);
            marker.setVisible(true);

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                console.log("MARKER");
                console.log(marker);
                console.log("MarkerID");
                console.log(marker.get('id'));
            });
        }
    },
```

so the console.log(marker.get('id')); is always the same and the console.log(marker) is always the same marker. How do i get the listener to add the specific marker?

Comment: Seems there are problems with the marker variable.. What does this.get('id') return?

Comment: the same id (12) even though i press on different markers. Because marker thats added to the event.addListener seams to be the same marker for all of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems to be a problem with the closures.. It always returns the last know marker.. You have to take the part of the clickhandler to a new function (outside).

Info: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events?csw=1#EventClosures

Replace the addEventListener with addClickHandler(marker);

```
function addClickHandler(theMarker) {
google.maps.event.addListener(theMarker, 'click', function() {
console.log(theMarker.get('id'));
  });
}
```